# Enable iOS application restriction for Firebase Authentication in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I am able to make the sign-in with the following code, when there is no application restriction on the key in the GoogleService-Info.plist file:

```
Future<void> linkWithGoogle() async {
    var googleProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();
    googleProvider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email');
    googleProvider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile');

    try {
      await _auth.currentUser!.linkWithProvider(googleProvider);
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
      log('Error: Failed to link with Google: ${e.code} - ${e.message}');
    }
}
```

But if I enable iOS application restriction by adding my apps bundle if in the google cloud console I get a 403 with the message: "Requests from this iOS client application <empty> are blocked."

I found that the app must be identified with a custom header (at least when using the API): `'x-ios-bundle-identifier': 'servicecontrol.googleapis.com/<bundle.id>'`.

How can this be done while using the SDK?